Add endpoints.MapHealthChecks in .NET 8 worker project
I have a Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker" in .net8.0 and I want to use kestrel in this project to host some endpoints for healthcheck. I did this in .net 5.0 but it doesn't work in .net 8.0.
Here is sample code of .net 5:
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    })

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                var allPredicate = new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                    ResponseWriter = HealthCheckTools.WriteResponse
                };
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc", allPredicate);
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc/startup", allPredicate);
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc/ready", allPredicate);
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc/live", allPredicate);
            });


"but it doesn't work" - how exactly it does not work?

The ConfigureWebHostDefaults extension method not exist in .net8.0 worker projects.

But UseEndpoints does? Do you have a [mre]? How do you create the project?

HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapHealthChecks is part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref metapackage, the easiest option to use it would be to just switch to the Web SDK:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    ...
</Project>

Hence just create an ordinary ASP.NET Core app (without any endpoints) and add your hosted services to it.
Alternatively you can add a FrameworkReference with Microsoft.AspNetCore.App but arguably it does not make much sense/difference.
